# Efficient manipulation of large, non-sparse arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, large-data

I have a row vector `q` with `200` elements, and another row vector, `dij`, which is the output of the `pdist` function with currently `48216200` elements, but I'd like to be able to go higher. The operation I want to do is essentially:

```
t=sum(q'*dij,2);
```

However, since this tries to allocate a `200x48211290` array, it complains that this would require 70GB of memory. Therefore I do it this way:

```
t = zeros(numel(q),1);
for i=1:numel(q)
    qi = q(i);
    factor = qi*dij;
    t(i)=sum(factor);
end
```

However, this takes too much time. By too much time, I mean it takes about `36s`, which is orders of magnitude longer than the time required by the `pdist` function. Is there a way I can speed up this operation without explicitly allocating so much memory? I'm assuming here, that if the first way could allocate the memory, (being a vector operation) it would be faster.

Comment: Try using Tall Arrays. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, good point.

Comment: Running your code with `dij` 1 million elements, the vectorized solution takes 0.58 seconds, the loop takes 0.13 seconds. Obviously the loop is the more efficient solution, as  this difference will only increase for larger arrays. Please time your code before assuming that the vectorized code is faster!

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson that didn't quite work, as during the `gather()` step it gave the same memory error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of multiplication with respect to addition:

```
t = q'*sum(dij);
```

Comment: in addition to this, you could convert data to single, e.g. single(dij), which reduces the memory by half.

Comment: Well so in my attempt to make the problem a minimal reproducible example, I made it too simple. The full thing I need to calculate is `sin(q*dij)./(q*dij)`. I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer because it's correct, but if you have any ideas about the version with the `sin` I'm all ears.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate I don't get it. How is `sin(q*dij)./(q*dij)` a generalization of `sum(q'*dij,2)`? No sum, no transpose? What are the sizes?

Comment: @LuisMendo sorry I meant `sum(sin(q*dij)./(q*dij),2)`.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate Are you still missing a transpose? Anyway, the sine spoils the distributive property, and can't think of a way to simplify it

Comment: yes it should be `q'`. thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate If you remove some of the intermediate variables in your loop code, you can speed it up: `t(i)=sum(q(i)*dij);`. The same is true for your version with `sin`. Putting things on one line allows the JIT to optimize computation in different ways. I bet the call to `sin` is the more expensive bit of your computation, and wouldn't be much better in a vectorized operation.

Answer (score 0):

for testing what Cris said in the first post comment I created 3 ".m" files as follows:

vec.m :

```
res=sum(sin(d.*q')./(d.*q'));
```

forloop.m

```
for i=1:200
    res(i)=sum(sin(d.*q(i))./(d.*q(i)));
end
```

and test.m:

```
clc
clear all
d=rand(4e6,1);
q=rand(200,1);
res=zeros(1,200);

forloop;
vec;
forloop;
vec;
forloop;
vec;
```

then I used matlab run and time profiler ,
the results were very surprising ! :

```
3 calls to forloop : ~10.5 S
3 call to vec : 15.5 S !!!
```

and additionally when I converted data to single the results were:

```
... forloop : 7.5 S
... vec : 8.5 S
```

I don't know precisely why for-loop is faster in these scenarios, but as for your problem, you could speed up things by generating lesser variables in the loop and using vertical vectors( i think). and finally converting your data to single values :

```
q=single(rand(200,1)); 
...
```

Comment: Loops are not slow any more in MATLAB. They haven't been for a long time. 15 years ago, replacing a loop with vectorized code would speed up computation by 100x. Now it's maybe 2x in good cases. In contrast, using large intermediate arrays (which is often needed when vectorizing, as is the case here) is inefficient: the cache is not being used efficiently. This causes vectorized code, which was much faster than the equivalent loop 15 years ago, to be much slower than the loop today.

Comment: Some comments on your code: (1) always use `timeit` to time code, the profiler is not the optimal way of comparing execution time, it is meant to find the slower part of the code. The profiler probes the running code every so often, seeing what line of code is being run. `timeit` just times how long it takes to run a bit of code, runs the code for long enough to get a good timing, ignores "warmup time", etc. (2) `clear all` removes functions from memory. This causes their execution the first time to be slower. You should usually not need `clear all`, `clear` by itself is sufficient.

Comment: (3) You can write functions at the bottom of your script file, there is no longer a need to write each function in a separate M-file.